# Equation of a graph VS formula of a graph

Tags: terminology

Simple question:

> Why do refer to the *equation* of a straight line instead of the *formula* of a straight line?

For instance, formulae provide relationships between multiple variables, which is what something like $y=mx+c$ does. Equations, on the other hand, assert equality (which admittedly $y=mx+c$ does) but we tend to want them solved.

Comment: @Somos What I am trying to ask is why everyone talks about equations of graphs rather than formulae of graphs. It is common to describe $y=2x+1$ as an equation for the graph, but I am wondering why it is not as common to refer to it as a formula for the graph.

Answer (score 1):

One good reason to prefer the equation of a geometric object is if you go beyond
one linear equation in one variable. For example, an equation of a circle is
$\,(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2.\,$ Here, both variables $\,x\,$ and $\,y\,$ are treated
simultaneously. If written as a formula $\,y = \text{[something]}\,$ then there
are two values of $\,y\,$ for values of $\,x.\,$ A similar example is the equation
of a degenerate conic being two lines. The equation is something like
$\, 0 = (y-ax-b)(y-cx-d).\,$ Again, writing $\,y\,$ as a formula needs two values.